# When did MacOS fully transition to 64-bit?

Tags: osx, macintosh, 64bit, apple

In [this Arstechnica article](https://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2009/08/mac-os-x-10-6/5/) on the release of Mac OS X snow leopard, it included this graphic:[image: OS X Architecture Overview]
Following Snow Leopard, when did apps, Cocoa, and Carbon also transition to 64 bit? By what release was OS X/MacOS fully 64-bit?

Comment: The answer is a bit fuzzy and by 10,5 I think being fully 64 bits depended wether your EFI supported booting in 64-bits or not. I suspect the graphics are incomplete or memory might be betraying me.

Answer (score 1):

How are you defining "fully" 64-bit?

```
% file /usr/bin/perl
/usr/bin/perl: Mach-O universal binary with 2 architectures: [x86_64:Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64] [i386:Mach-O executable i386]
/usr/bin/perl (for architecture x86_64):        Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64
/usr/bin/perl (for architecture i386):  Mach-O executable i386
% sw_vers
ProductName:    Mac OS X
ProductVersion: 10.13.5
BuildVersion:   17F77
```

Answer (score 0):

With that figure, Apple indicates the system (that is fully 64bit since *Snow Leopard*)
is able to run **both** 32bit and 64bit apps